# How to pass in a type to a class

Tags: c++, templates, types

I need to pass in a  type to a class.  The code below works but I was wondering if it is the best way to do this.  Are there better ways?

```
template<typename T, typename M>
class BinaryParser
{
public:
   BinaryParser(T& decoder, unsigned header_size) 
      :  m_decoder(decoder), m_header_size(header_size) {}

   virtual bool Parse() {
      M message;
      //do something with message
      return true;
   }

protected:
   T&                  m_decoder;
   unsigned            m_header_size;  
}; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int a1, b1;
   a1=1;
   b1=2;
   BinaryParser<int,string> bp(a1,b1);
   bp.Parse();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you have seems fine -- do you see any downsides?  What motivated the question?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I was not missing out on some amazing clever way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make the `Parse` member function virtual if you are not re-implementing it in sub-classes (as it seems from your example code). Instead you can provide a **template method**. You would probably want to require template parameter type to have some defined interface:

```
template <typename M>
bool Parse() {
    M message; // M must be default constructable
    // ... parse message from a stream or something
    m_decoder.decode( message.getBytes()); // M must have getBytes() member
    return message.isValid(); // M must have isValid() member
}
```

Then use it like:

```
BinaryParser<int> bp(a1,b1);

if ( bp.Parse<string>()) { /* parsed */ }
if ( bp.Parse<some_other_type>()) { /* parsed */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ is a s[tatically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statically_typed#Static_typing) language with very [limited type introspection capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), using templates is the best way to pass a type to a class, and the only way to let a class create new instances of a type. An alternative would be to pass `typeid`, but it would not work for your example, because it does not let you define new instances.

Comment: I did take a look at typeid and came to same conclusion.